# Using spring cli behind proxy results in "Connection refused" error

Tags: spring, proxy, spring-boot

I am struggling to get spring cli running behind our corporate proxy. I read some suggestions in spring blogs on how to set the proxy and tried to follow, but w/o any success so far.

I tried the following

- set http.proxyHost, http.proxyPort, http.proxyUser, http.proxyPassword as windows env variable
- set corresponding variables for https as well
- set JAVA_OPTS env. variable with -D...
- verified that JAVA_OPTS variables are correctly picked up by setting debug on

Based on the above settings, the startup script is actually using the below command to run the spring cli

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66/bin/java.exe" -Dhttp.proxyHost=http://webproxy.company.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=https://webproxy.company.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyUser=zencv -Dhttp.proxyPassword=dadada -cp "C:\My programs\spring-1.3.5.RELEASE\bin\\..\lib\*" org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher init
```

I am always getting the same error

```
Using service at https://start.spring.io
Failed to retrieve metadata from service at 'https://start.spring.io'     (Connect to start.spring.io:443 [start.spring.io/141.101.112.192, start.spring.io/190.93.243.191] failed: Connection refused: conn
ect)
```

In-order to verify that I can reach the site from a command line using the above proxy, I used curl with proxy and was successful. Please help!